# Slow running SQL Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the developers complaining that their report is running very slow and when I run sp_who2 and run the SQL Profiler it shows that there is a lots of blocking caused by some system queries. How can I fix this issue now? Can somebody please give me idea.

Thanks,

Comment: Going to be impossible to tell without further details like table structures, queries being run, and server configurations.

Comment: maybe the network printer is connected to your database server? :-)  ok.. just post the blocking query here, or even table structure, it would take out a lot of guessworks on the cause of the problem. please profile the blocking query too, try to fix the query if it has bottlenecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons :

1. Many SQL Jobs running in your SQL Server where you extracting data
2. Query is not Optmize

Solution :

1. Stop SQL Jobs running in your SQL Server that you do not use
2. Optimize your Query in your SP to make it more faster and use CTE's.

Regards